# I have a .csv file that contains the edges of a graph (Name1, Name2). How do I convert this into a adjacency matrix?

Tags: python, csv, machine-learning, graph, networkx

I'm doing a machine learning project on Python that requires me to process some data and convert them into an adjacency matrix. The data is saved in csv files, and are saved as such:

```
114787,375519
114787,285613
114787,7448
114787,4914
114787,51343
.
.
```

The problem is, these numbers **do not represent indices but just names**. There are only 19000 nodes or so, and the numbers in the .csv file are basically random names given to the various nodes of a graph.

I need to put all these into an adjacency matrix while retaining the information about which index is represented by which name and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do so. Would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0):

I think below way will work.

```py
import networkx as nx

f = open("edge_lst.csv", "rb")
G = nx.read_edgelist(f) 
f.close()
```

Comment: I did try that, but I'm supposed to turn it into an adjacency matrix.

After running nx.adjacency_matrix(G) the indices seem no longer retain the strings indicating the names of the nodes in question